# datagridview export to excel

Tags: c#

I could export data of datagridview to excel. But the actual format of datagridview was not exported i.e., font, color and space. So, is there any best way to export datagridview to excel i.e. not only data but also the look.

The sample look is this:

[image]

Comment: it looks like you are displaying some sort of a report. I would suggest you use Crystal Reports or SSRS. They have built in facilities to export to other formats. If you manually do the export you will have to modify the exporting function every time your report format change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try CSV export

```
private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
    {
        string separator = ",";
        StringBuilder stOutput = new StringBuilder();
        // Export titles: 
        StringBuilder sHeaders = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            sHeaders.Append(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText);
            sHeaders.Append(separator);
        }
        stOutput.AppendLine(sHeaders.ToString());
        // Export data. 
        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder stLine = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < dGV.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                stLine.Append(Convert.ToString(dGV[j, i].Value));
                stLine.Append(separator);
            }
            stOutput.AppendLine(stLine.ToString());
        }

        File.WriteAllText(filename, stOutput.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I am getting an error as `'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cells' ` can you help me

Comment: This has so many errors in it!  dGV.Rows.Cells should be dGV.Rows[i].Cells and for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++) should be for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount; i++)

Answer (score 0):

Before you write code in button_Click event, you must add a reference to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel object library.

Right click on your project and select Add Reference menu. After that go to .NET tab and select and add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Write the below code in button_Click event.

```
            // button_Click event

           private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
                // creating Excel Application
                string fileName = String.Empty;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                // creating new WorkBook within Excel application
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                // creating new Excelsheet in workbook
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
                // see the excel sheet behind the program
                app.Visible = true;
                // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
                // store its reference to worksheet
                try
                {
                     //Fixed:(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
                     worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
                     worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;
                     // changing the name of active sheet
                     worksheet.Name = "Exported from AMIT";
                     // storing header part in Excel
                     for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                     {
                          worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                     }
                     // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
                     for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                     {
                          for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                          {
                               worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                          }
                     }


                     // Save The Application
                     SaveFileDialog saveFileExcel = new SaveFileDialog();

                     saveFileExcel.Filter = "Excel files |*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                     saveFileExcel.FilterIndex = 2;
                     saveFileExcel.RestoreDirectory = true;


                     if (saveFileExcel.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                     {
                          fileName = saveFileExcel.FileName;
                          //Fixed-old code :11 para->add 1:Type.Missing
                          workbook.SaveAs(fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                     }
                     else
                     {
                           return;

                           // Exit from the application
                           //app.Quit();
                     }
               }
               catch (Exception)
               {
                     //Statement;
               }
               finally
               {
                     app.Quit();
                     workbook = null;
                     app = null;
               }
          }
```